# I would like to limit the input How can I do it? (chess board)

Tags: python

I would like to limit the input. The user can enter a letter (a-h) and an integer (1-8) for example c4 (chess board) How can I do it?
This is my code:

```
square  = input("Enter a chess square identifier : ") 

if (ord(square[0]))%2 != int(square [1])%2:

    print("white")
else:
    print( "black")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like the below

```
def is_valid_square(square: str) -> bool:
    # TODO add values up to 8
    return len(square) == 2 and square[0] in {'a', 'b', 'c'} and square[1] in {'1', '2', '3'}
```